# Processwire unable to edit root page

Tags: php, .htaccess, processwire

I have a weird issue with Processwire 3.0.146. Whenever I try to edit my root page in the backend I get the "Bookmarks" section instead of the edit page view. I also had this problem on 3.0.123.

`(-> http://localhost/processwire/page/edit/bookmarks/)`

The link target of the root page in the backend, however is shown as:

`http://localhost/processwire/page/edit/?id=1`

So there seems to be some redirect happening in between. Has anyone ever faced such an issue? Any help would be appreciated, since I basically can't edit my homepage.

//edit: I thought about removing the bookmarks module since I don't need it, which should in theory help with the problem. I wasn't able to find bookmarks as a standalone plugin that can be deactivated. Is this possible? I thought about this being a apache2 problem, but I've had this issue on three different machines (a vagrant lamp-stack, a docker-compose lamp stack and a plain old local lamp stack on my machine).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Greetings derelektrischemoench

Comment: It seems to be an issue specific to your installation only. It could be some `.htaccess` redirect, a cache issue or something like that. It is hard to guess not having the ability to examine the site. If you think you need more personalized help please visit ProcessWire forums to get it.

Comment: Hi @ivangretsky; thanks for the input, I found the culprit. Somehow my mod_rewrite wasn't working correctly. I reinstalled apache which fixed the problem.